# Rails - ctrl-c ignored after starting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-prompt

I have Ruby v1.9.3 and Rails v3.2.3 on Win7. I have no problem generating a Rails directory and starting the Ruby server, but what happens is that once the server is started I have no prompt and no code I type seems to execute.

to be specific - here is the terminal code from a session:

```
 => Booting WEBrick
 => Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
 => Call with -d to detach
 => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
 [2012-04-30 06:25:06] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
 [2012-04-30 06:25:06] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
 [2012-04-30 06:25:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2112 port=3000
```

after this point there is no prompt and no command I type seems to produce a result (including ctrl-c).

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked: Im doing a rails tutorial and this was the got me back on track. Ctrl-Pause/Break stopped the server.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're running `rails server` to get to this point.

Everything is working as it should. Rails is a web framework and when you run it in server mode it doesn't accept commands from the terminal. Instead Rails listens for web requests on port 3000 and responds appropriately. While the server is running the terminal window is displaying the internal server logs. Visit http://localhost:3000 while the server is running and you'll see what I mean.

If you want some command line interactivity, run `rails console` instead. This will load up your Rails environment but instead of listening for web requests on a port it'll give you an irb prompt where you can type ruby.

Comment: "it doesn't accept commands from the terminal" so why it claims that I can use Ctrl-C to shutdown server?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I meant that it isn't accepting ruby commands. Ctrl-C is the shutdown command. It's supposed to take you back to the regular terminal but on Windows it's always a bit finnicky. Try Ctrl-Pause/Break instead and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-Pause/Break works. "Pause/Break" confused me for a little bit, so if you are new like me it is the key usually next to F12 that says "pause break". :)